# LaTeX array variable

Tags: arrays, latex3, variable

Can't seem to figure out how to create a variable containing multiple numbers.

```
\def\numbers{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25}}

\numbers[1][1]
```

Expected output

```
1
```

Actual output

```
1,2,3,4,5,...,[1][1]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. You define `\numbers` to write string of numbers `1,2,... ,25`-  So result is expected. ˙[1][1]˛` are not defined as part of `\numbers` command, so they are simple added to string. It is not clear, what you after with this command definitions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX does not do magic.

WIth `\def\numbers{...}` you define a macro that expands to `...` and

```
\numbers[1][1]
```

just prints the definition of `\numbers` followed by `[1][1]`.

You can do it by *programming* arrays. Happily, `expl3` provides the necessary infrastructure, namely clists.

We define a clist whose items are clists and it's easy to retrieve the items by row and column index.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setarray}{mm}
 {% #1 = name, #2 = items
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_swepz_array_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_swepz_array_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getarrayitem}{mmm}
 {% #1 = name, #2 = row index, #3 = column index
  \clist_item:en
   {
    \clist_item:cn { l_swepz_array_#1_clist } { #2 }
   }
   { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setarray{numbers}{
  {1,2,3,4,5},
  {6,7,8,9,10},
  {11,12,13,14,15},
  {16,17,18,19,20},
  {21,22,23,24,25}
}

\getarrayitem{numbers}{1}{1}

\getarrayitem{numbers}{4}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Newlines are not necessary in `\setarray`, but they're better for clarity.

Comment: Thank you! How you do disable the newline?

Comment: @Swepz You can use whatever linebreak  you want, or none.